# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in node.js

Tags: node.js

Please excuse me for my incompetence.

Can I Redirect a *http* request to *https* request in node.js, Without running the *http* server?
Is it possible to only use *https* server on node.js and redirect *http* request to https?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. HTTP and HTTPS needs to listen on different ports. This depends on that they are different protocol types. Therefore you need two servers. Also in Apache and Nginx you need 2 Configurations for handling the redirects between HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Hey can you refer me some documents on this? - dtomasi

Comment: Thank you Brother. I appreciate your help.